# NetBeans won't open FileZilla files

Tags: netbeans, filezilla

I installed NetBeans 7.2.1 for Ubuntu 12.0.4.

When I connect via FTP to a site and click view/edit a file (FileZilla), NetBeans is opened but without a file in it (it only opens NetBeans without opening the file).

Anyone had a similar issue?

Could it be permission issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears I had misconfigured file type associations in FileZilla:

It is supposed to look like this:

> html /usr/bin/gedit
>
> php /home/denis/netbeans-7.2.1/bin/netbeans
>
> . /usr/bin/gedit

Comment: I was trying to configure it but was wrong: `php home/ivan/netbeans-7.2.1/bin/netbeans` (slash missed before 'home'). You made my day

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Filezilla.
2. Click on **Edit** tab and then click on **Settings**.
3. A new window will apear then click on **Filetype Associations**
4. Enter path to **netbeans** executable for example : (`php /home/denis/netbeans-7.2.1/bin/netbeans`) [all php file will be open by this netbeans]